# 3D device simulation of diode (static)

Tags: simulation

I am looking for a simple 3d software solving the drift and diffusion model
for a diode in equilibrium. (Very simple abrupt p/n-junction - even without contacts. Purpose: teaching).

I know Silvaco Atlas and Synopsis. However, their licenses are far too expensive
for my very simple experiment.

Is somebody aware of shareware that I could use?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Would ElectricalEngineering.SE possibly be a better place for this?

Comment: Have you checked nanohub.org? They have various web interfaces to highly professional semiconductor solvers. For teaching why not use a 1D model?

Comment: There are a lot of free tools in [nanohub.org](http://nanohub.org/resources/tools). But not sure about this specific one. Make a search there.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! A 1d-model is not enough in my case. In fact, I would like to model p/n-junctions with different 3d-geometries at equilibrium. I checked on nanohub, but did not find anything appropriate. Thus, I would appreciate further help.

Comment: Write something up in Matlab?

Comment: Have you checked into teaching licenses for the software you mentioned? Most companies that sell engineering software have very steep discounts for teaching use. Some even give licenses away for free.

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious, would an FEM library suffice for your needs? Although you may need to do some of the work implementing the solver for drift and diffusion, openfoam is a free library similar to comsol that could possibly fulfill your needs. Then again, perhaps the exact thing you are hoping to avoid is having to write your own solver.

Perhaps something like [Meep](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Meep)?

Comment: To be honest, I do not know what a FEM libary is. It sounds like a lot of programming? Actually this is what I would like to circumvent for this very simple experiment.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method